# Value for ncomp when making predictions for PLSR model

Tags: r, prediction, partial-least-squares

Using the `seatpos` dataset from the `faraway` package in R, I wanted to do PLS regression models with up to eight components, choose the one with lowest RMSE as optimal model, and make predictions with it. 
So I first created the models and computed the RMSEs for each of them:

```
> plsmod <- plsr(hipcenter ~ .,data=seatpos,ncomp=8,validation='CV')
> plsCV <- RMSEP(plsmod,estimate='CV')
```

Plotting RMSEP vs number of components, it can be seen that the model with lowest RMSE has three components:

```
> plot(plsCV,main='')
```

[image]

The lowest RMSEP thus corresponds to the model with three components, which corresponds to `plsCV[4]`:

```
> plsCV
(Intercept)      1 comps      2 comps      3 comps      4 comps      5 comps       
      60.45        45.90        40.54        38.62        42.36        43.54    
6 comps      7 comps     8 comps  
    45.05        45.12        45.33
```

Looking to the plot, the output for `plsCV`, and the documentation of `plsr()` I would specify `ncmop = 3` in `predict()`, but if I followed the same way of analysis as for PCR in the book of Faraway, then I should use the output for `which.min(plsCV$val)`, i.e. 4 in my case,  for `ncomp`.

So, when using `predict()` in my PLS model, do I need to specify `ncomp = 3` or `ncomp = 4`?

Comment: Is there something against testing both in generating the predictions? I mean it seems that you have a theoretical justification for using 4 components, based on Faraway, and a more practical justification for using 3 components based on your results. For the latter you could argue that it is sensitive to idiosyncrasies of the data and therefore prefer the theoretical justification of 4 components. Btw I am not familiar with this type of modeling so your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: When testing i see that `ncomp=4` gives lower RMSE:   
  `> rmse <- function(x,y) sqrt(mean((x-y)^2))   
 > rmse(predict(plsmod,ncomp = 3),seatpos$hipcenter)  
 [1] 34.17719  
 > rmse(predict(plsmod,ncomp = 4),seatpos$hipcenter)    
[1] 33.19577 `   
 But how to concile that with the plot and plsCV values?

Comment: The first element in the array is the intercept, which is probably constant prediction as mean. So your 4th element in the array is already corresponding to RMSEP of ncomp=3. And since you need to provide ncomp, NOT the index in the array, ncomp=3 is the way to go.

Comment: in other words, which.min(plsCV$val) returns the index of the minimum in the array. Maybe at the release day of book, RMSEP for intercept was not present.

Comment: @theGD that is what i thought, yet ncomp=4 gave a smaller RMSE as i showed above. So how can this be?

Comment: R is not my main language.  Which error is less for ncomp=4? RMSE of predicting training data or validation data? Either way, most of the time one selects ncomp according to CV errors, so if your RMSE for validation predictions happens to be lower for 4 comps, that doesn't mean it will outperform 3 comps all the time. It is the very reason of using CV, having a somewhat reliable estimation of ncomp without involving independent test data.

Comment: The error is less for ncomp=4 using training data, that is what i do not understand

Comment: I believe your confusion is about the difference between CV RMSE and training set RMSE. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `which.min(plsCV$val) = 4` indicates that the model with `ncomp = 3` is the one with lowest RSME:

```
# 4th element in plsCV$val has the minimum RSME:
> which.min(plsCV$val) 
[1] 4


# 4th RSME in plsCV$val:
> plsCV$val[4] 
[1] 38.70445



# 4th element in plsCV$val corresponds to RSME for ncomp = 3
plsCV$val 


, , model = (Intercept)

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV  60.44806

, , model = 1 comps

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV  45.78991

, , model = 2 comps

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV  40.94971

, , model = 3 comps

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV  38.70445

, , model = 4 comps

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV  42.30152

, , model = 5 comps

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV  44.46387

, , model = 6 comps

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV  46.20819

, , model = 7 comps

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV  45.96724

, , model = 8 comps

        response
estimate hipcenter
      CV   46.2512
```

Answer (score 0):

With cross-validation the basic steps for your case is:
Starting with 
ncomp=1

1. Remove a fixed portion of data from training set
2. Build a model with ncomp = 1 with the remaining data
3. Predict the removed samples
4. Compare the prediction with the actual values of removed samples (again for removed samples ofc.)
5. Put the removed samples back into training set
6. If all samples are removed once, calculate an average error, otherwise go to step 2

By doing so, an error estimate is calculated for ncomp=1. Similarly, for each ncomp the error is calculated. *This is to somewhat simulate the performance of each ncomp on unseen data.*

On the other hand, autoprediction errors, that is calculating RMSE for each ncomp using *entire training set each time*, can provide a minimum RMSE **for THAT DATA SET.** In fact, for PLS, if you use all possible components you may end up with a nearly zero RMSE for training set while performing very bad on validation set or on any other unseen data.

99% of the time, CV is better for finding optimum parameter (ncomp) because it provides a good estimate for a higher **predictive performance on unseen data or in other words for avoiding overfitting.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I am too new to R and PLS, so it is very possible I am missing/misunderstanding something. I thought that using CV with the training set for each ncomp would allow to see which ncomp is best, i.e. yields lowest RMSE, to build the model, as shown in the graph above. Since the graph shows the lowest RMSE corresponds to ncomp=3, I thought that the smallest RMSE for the predictions using the whole training set would correspond to ncomp=3 as well. However the lowest RMSE for the predictions corresponds to ncomp=4,as seen in the output shown in the comments.

Comment: So is it clear now?

Comment: So even though the RMSE of the prediction is smaller when `ncomp=4` as `which.min(plsCV$val)` suggests, in order to build the model i need to use `ncomp=3` as both the graph and `plsCV` indicate, correct?